# Recent ideas in Macaulayfication?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Kawasaki has shown that a quasi-projective variety over a field has a Macaulayfication.  His construction does not preserve the Cohen-Macaulay locus of the original variety, only a finite set of points in the Cohen-Macaulay locus.  Have there been any recent improvements of Kawasaki's result that give Macaulayfications that preserve the entire Cohen-Macaulay locus of the original variety?

Comment: Is there a Gorensteinification?

Comment: To make a scheme Cohen-Macaulay, it suffices to apply a modification so that a given generically finite morphism to a smooth scheme (e.g., linear projection to projective space) becomes a finite, flat morphism to a smooth scheme, ala Raynaud-Gruson.  The problem is that the morphism to a smooth scheme is not canonical, so cannot be constructed locally.

Comment: I've had a number of conversations with people about this over the years.  We've all agreed that Kawasaki's construction doesn't seem to work.  Unfortunately, I don't know of anyone actively working on this.

Comment: Also, I do not think we have a Gorensteinification unfortunately.  It's a question of Kollár whether or not you can have a rationalification (rational singularities).  You can do some things like this for singularities of the MMP (for instance see the recent paper of Hacon-Xu in the LC case).

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Gorensteinification, it is possible to start with a demi-normal (ie, G_1, S_2, and seminormal) quasi-projective variety U and find a demi-normal projective closure.  This is not really a Gorensteinification, but something close to normalization without completely normalizing a given projective closure of U.  Also, for Q-Gorenstein varieties at least, the cyclic covering lemma with Cohen-Macaulayfication would probably do the trick.

Comment: The cyclic cover is not birational to the original, so this would not give a Gorensteinification.